# sublime text 3 and package control

Tags: sublimetext3

I installed sublime text 3 editor and package control on my computer, but many of the packages only work on sublime text 2. However, I read articles on how branching to st3 could be a work around. But, I have no idea what that means, how can one branch to st3?

Answer (score 15):

Please follow the instructions at: https://packagecontrol.io/installation

Comment: also checkout my first plugin https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Console%20Wrap%20for%20js

Comment: Don't use these instructions. They are out-of-date. Instead follow the directions at https://packagecontrol.io/installation.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean in Package Control or for other packages? For Package Control, you need to manually clone the git repo. Then do `git checkout python3`. For installing packages, you need to add the branch URLs as an external repository. For example, one of my plugins that I have a ST3 branch on is AdvancedNewFile. To install the ST3 branch, I would have do the following.

1. In the command palette search for "Package Control: Add Repository"
2. In the input panel, insert https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile/tree/ST3
3. Install AdvancedNewFile normally through package control.

The URL can be found by clicking the Branch dropdown on github and selecting the appropriate branch.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a Sublime 2 Package on Sublime 3, you can install the Package Manager as described [here](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation).

Then `CTRL+ALT+P` > `Package Control: Add Repository` > Paste the GitHub (or repository) URL > Install the package normally.

This doesn't guarantee the package will work, so you must check if there's a branch or something which is compatible with Sublime 3. I did that with [freewizard/SublimeFormatSQL](https://github.com/freewizard/SublimeFormatSQL) since one of the commits said 'Added Sublime Text 3 support', and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime tries to write some config files to your .conf directory located in /home/{username}/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages but it hasn't writing permission.
So try:

```
chmod -R 777 /home/{username}/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages
```

Open the console and try to paste to code for sublime text 3.

Answer (score 0):

Manual Installation

If for some reason the console installation instructions do not work for you (such as having a proxy on your network), perform the following steps to manually install Package Control:

1. Click the Preferences > Browse Packages… menu and close sublime text 3
2. Browse up a folder and then into the Installed Packages/ folder
3. Download Package Control.sublime-package and copy it into the Installed Packages/ directory
4. go to this address https://github.com/wbond/package_control/blob/master/Package%20Control.sublime-settings
   copy the code
5. open the copied downloaded "Package Control.sublime-package" in Installed Package (double click the package)
6. edit the file Package Control.sublime-settings in downloaded Package Control.sublime-package and replace the code that you copied in github
7. save and close Package Control.sublime-package
8. start Sublime Text 3 and wait to install package and restart

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use the packages which are fully supported in your Sublime Text 3 version.

1. You can browse packages easily from: https://packagecontrol.io as well as see their compatibility.
2. Another method can be simply go to to your Sublime Text 3 > Install packages & Install the package you need. Here; you only see the packages supported in your Sublime Text 3 version.

Hope it helps...